# Are there infinite many positive integers $\ n\ $ satisfying $\ \varphi(n)|\sigma(n)\ $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum

Today I suddenly discovered that many positive integers $\ n\ $ satisfy $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)\ $. This leads to the following question :

> Are there infinitely many postive integers $\ n\ $ satisfying
> $$\varphi(n)|\sigma(n)$$
> where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler’s totient function,and $\sigma(n)$ is  the sum of divisors of $n$ ? If yes , can it be proven ?

The first few such $\ n\ $ are $$n=1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 14, 15, 30, 35, 42, 56, 70, 78, 105, 140, 168, 190$$

Ideas for a proof of the existence of infinite many such positive integers (like families of such numbers probably being infinite) are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is true?

Comment: so I post here ask it

Comment: @MichaelMorrow,I can't prove it.Thanks

Comment: Just to save everyone else a search:  this is [A020492](https://oeis.org/A020492) on OEIS.  That page doesn't say anything about infinitude, but it does give a family of examples coming from Mersenne primes, so it seems reasonable to conjecture the set is infinite.

Comment: Such questions very often turn out to be out of reach. I do not claim that a proof is impossible, but I think it will be very difficult. I think, the best we can do is to find families that are very "likely" to be infinite (perhaps more "likely" than the set of Mersenne primes)

Comment: Apart from the fact, that the half of an even perfect number has always this property, I found this $86$-digit number by successively searching the smallest multiple of the previous number with the desired proerty : $$47719512409785681502573384363698309025494972169324115397316491538122603073497662208000$$ giving ratio $82$. Beginning with $360$ instead of $1$ gives this $118$-digit number $$1148504009465272175627834753030942352103403312153640921407359886545801129099618157116738871410493364712355222969088000$$ giving ratio $91$

Comment: By the way, there are even huge squarefree solutions, for example this monster : $$148504621260915439590480104525880008534525196529172773528290153939780712483230238657438737509145961295133297108620156439175622984987119112903647214652622780573688542572639027308346330$$ with $40$ prime factors giving ratio $15$.

Comment: Crossposted to [mathoverflow.se]: [Are there infinitely many positive integers $\ n\ $ satisfying $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/418927)

Comment: There is also https://oeis.org/A062699 which has some nice references: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Broughan/broughan26.html and https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Broughan/bro32.html.