# Are there infinite many squarefree numbers with $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)\ $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum

This question is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4407570/82961) post.

> I wonder whether the number of squarefree integers $\ n\ge 2\ $ with $\ \varphi(n)\mid \sigma(n)\ $ is still infinite. As in the link , $\ \varphi(n)\ $ is the totient function and $\ \sigma(n)\ $ the divisor - sum function. The first $\ 40\ $ such numbers are : $$[2, 3, 6, 14, 15, 30, 35, 42, 70, 78, 105, 190, 210, 357, 418, 570, 714, 910, 1045, 1254, 2090, 2730, 3135, 4522, 4674, 5278, 6270, 10659, 12441, 13566, 14630, 15834, 16770, 20026, 21318, 23374, 24871, 24882, 24969, 25070]$$

I think that for a given number of prime factors, there are only finite many such numbers (can someone prove this ?) , but still infinite many such numbers could exist.

Below $\ 10^9\ $ there are $1126$ such numbers , the following table summarizes the number of numbers with $1,2,\cdots , 9$ prime factors

```
1  2
2  4
3  9
4  28
5  171
6  487
7  340
8  81
9  4
```

The $\ 183\ $- digit number $$148504621260915439590480104525880008534525196529172773528290153939780712483230238657438737509145961295133297108620156439175622984987119112903647214652622780573688542572639027308346330$$ gives ratio $15$ and has $40$ prime factors :

$$[2, 3, 5, 11, 19, 29, 31, 53, 97, 137, 269, 457, 757, 1741, 4987, 8731, 25013, 30211, 30631, 46511, 51797, 53101, 59921, 74729, 231223, 430949, 440399, 451249, 662029, 858001, 1061759, 7320541, 10086707, 11625827, 13551379, 13992817, 20885069, 23868931, 94944263, 4346121576069167]$$

There are $\ 941\ $ such numbers with no prime factor exceeding $\ 100\ $

Comment: These numbers (without the squarefree restriction) are tabulated, with many links, at https://oeis.org/A020492

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000002981975209) is a squarefree$291$-digit number with $113$ prime factors giving ratio $78$

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000002987313291) is a squarefree $2184$-digit number with $664$ prime factors giving ratio $134$

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003001447106) is a new record : number of digits is $5\ 052$ , number of prime factors is $1\ 338$ including the first $1\ 000$ primes and the ratio is $159$.

Comment: No, @Peter, the downvoting here is entirely inappropriate. I was one of the upvoters!

Comment: The first $10000$ of these numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A078557 – number $10000$ is $358946138342$.